# How to extract local time from Firestore server timestamp?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

- I basically use **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()** to store timestamp in firestore
- I also understand that serverTimestamp is based on **UTC** so when I retrieve it, I need to convert to **local timestamp**
- I need the local **time** as a **string**

Problem is that I am successfully able to convert the server date to local date but not able to extract the time as a string. Here is the code:

```
let serverTimestamp = getFirestoreTimestampFromServer()
let utcTimestamp: Int64 = Int64(serverTimestamp.dateValue().timeintervalSince1970)
let localTimezoneOffsetFromUtc = Int64(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
let localTimestamp = utcTimestamp + localTimezoneOffsetFromUtc
        
let localDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(integerLiteral: localTimestamp))
print(localDate)
//This works, I get the local date as 2020-07-20 20:10:40 +0000
//So server timestamp is successfully converted
//BUT----

let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
let localTimeString = dateFormatter1.string(from: localDate)
print(localTimeString)
```

When I print the local time string, I get **"1:40"** instead of **"20:10"**. For your reference, my local time is 5 hours ahead of GMT or my server time.

Again, timestamp is getting converted successfully but not the extract time as a string portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't have to use secondsFromGMT. Use Timestamp.dateValue().timeintervalSince1970 and simply use a dateformatter on this to get the required time

```
let serverGMTTime = getServerTime() as? Timestamp
let convertedTime = Int(serverTime.dateValue().timeintervalSince1970)
let localDate = Date(timeintervalSince1970: TimeInterval(integerLiteral: convertedTime)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
let stringLocalTime = dateFormatter.string(from: localDate)
```