# How can I get the Datevalue from firestore Fieldvalue?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Inside my DTO I am using the Firestore FieldValue
for storing the serverside timestamp when adding/updating data: `@ServerTimestampConverter() required FieldValue creationTimestamp`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue

So inside my database there is an actual Timestamp Documentfield:

[image]

However, when trying to access my DTO value which is from type `FieldValue` I am not able to cast any Datevalue as it says:

```
FieldValue is not a subtype of type Timestamp
```

. As far as I know, FieldValue is only a sentinel which is set when adding/updating a field on firestore. But how am I able to read the documentfield and use the Datevalue in my app?

Here is a snippet from the codebase:

```
@freezed
abstract class KeekzCardDto implements _$KeekzCardDto {
  const factory KeekzCardDto({
    required String keekzDescription,
    @ServerTimestampConverter() required FieldValue creationTimestamp,
    required String keekzCaption,
  }) = _KeekzCardDto;

//! To Domain Models
  KeekzCard toDomain() {
    return KeekzCard(
      freeOfCharge: freeOfCharge,
      handicapAccessible: handicapAccessible,
      address: address.toDomain(),
      //dateTimeStamp: DateTimeStamp(creationTimestamp!),
      caption: KeekzCardCaption(keekzCaption),
      description: KeekzCardDescription(keekzDescription),
      ),
      creationTimeStamp: DateTimeStamp(
        (creationTimestamp as Timestamp).toDate().toString(),
      ),
   
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
My ServerTimestampConverter is looking like so:

```
class ServerTimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<FieldValue, Object> {
  const ServerTimestampConverter();

  @override
  FieldValue fromJson(Object json) {
    return FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(FieldValue fieldValue) => fieldValue;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012438/how-to-get-firestore-timestamp) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62998299/how-to-extract-local-time-from-firestore-server-timestamp) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996707/flutter-app-error-type-timestamp-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-datetime)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you have a look at it once.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Make @ServerTimestamoConvertor() like this:

```
class ServerTimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<FieldValue, Object> {
  const ServerTimestampConverter();

  @override
  FieldValue fromJson(Object json) {
    return FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(FieldValue fieldValue) => fieldValue;

  DateTime toDate(FieldValue fieldValue) { // <== added
    return fieldValue.toDate();
  }
}
```

and that will make the class as follows :

```
@freezed
abstract class KeekzCardDto implements _$KeekzCardDto {
  const factory KeekzCardDto({
    required String keekzDescription,
    @ServerTimestampConverter() required FieldValue creationTimestamp,
    required String keekzCaption,
  }) = _KeekzCardDto;

  //! To Domain Models
  KeekzCard toDomain() {
    return KeekzCard(
      freeOfCharge: freeOfCharge,
      handicapAccessible: handicapAccessible,
      address: address.toDomain(),
      //dateTimeStamp: DateTimeStamp(creationTimestamp!),
      caption: KeekzCardCaption(keekzCaption),
      description: KeekzCardDescription(keekzDescription),
      creationTimeStamp: DateTimeStamp(
        creationTimestamp.toDate().toString(), // <== 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OR

use the creationTimestamp directly as a FieldValue object. Then, when you need to display or use the timestamp in your app, you can handle it separately, without casting it to a DateTime object.

```
KeekzCard toDomain() {
  return KeekzCard(
    freeOfCharge: freeOfCharge,
    handicapAccessible: handicapAccessible,
    address: address.toDomain(),
    caption: KeekzCardCaption(keekzCaption),
    description: KeekzCardDescription(keekzDescription),
    creationTimestamp: creationTimestamp, // Keep it as FieldValue
  );
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I received the same error. Seems that I cannot cast FieldValue directly to Timestamp

Comment: From which package you are using @freezed and @ServerTimestampConverter() annotations ?

Comment: I edited the initial question and added the code for it, it was its own class